# Favicon Display Issue using IE

Tags: visualforce, community, favicon

Custom favicon for customer community is correctly displayed using Chrome but not in IE. 
In IE, favicon shows on home page but navigating to any other page it reverts back to the Salesforce cloud. Any Idea why?